# Check if multiple control types are empty inside groupbox and display tags of empty controls

Tags: vb.net, select, datepicker, textbox, numericupdown

As mentioned i need to check if all fields in a groupbox are empty and if they are then display a messagebox showing the tags of the empty fields.

Issue is i have multiple types of controls on this box including: TextBox, NumericUpDown and DatePicker.

I am wondering if there is an easier way than what i am doing below.

```
        If BenchQtyCombo.Text = 1 Then
            Dim B1emptyTextBoxes =
            From txt In Bench1_Combo.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            Where txt.Text.Length = 0
            Select txt.Tag

            Dim B1emptyNumericBox =
            From num In Bench1_Combo.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)()
            Where num.Value = 0
            Select num.Tag

            If B1emptyTextBoxes.Any Or B1emptyNumericBox.Any Then
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please Complete the Following Required Fields:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "{0}", String.Join(", ", B1emptyTextBoxes, B1emptyNumericBox)))

            End If
        End If
```

Im also having an issue with `B1emptyTextBoxes, B1emptyNumericBox` displaying the tags in the messagebox as i get [this string instead of the tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDMrJ.png)

Im yet to include the code for the datepicker which will be something like `Where DatePicker.Date > Today` code yet until i get this working.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, a group box's text property can never equal 1. 1 is a numeric type. Normally a text property contains a string.

```
If GroupBox1.Text = "1" Then
```

Next, a .Tag property is of datatype Object. You can throw anything you want into it. However, you will get an object when you reference it. When you call .ToString on an Object (which is what your String.Format is doing) you will get the fully qualified name of the Object.

The CStr() changes it back to the underlying type String. If you hold your cursor over B1emptyTextBoxes and B1emptyNumericBox befor adding the CStr() you will see that the datatype is IEnumerable of Object. After adding CStr() you will see IEnumerable of String.

Then add the 2 IEnumerables together with the Concat() method and Bob's your uncle.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    If GroupBox1.Text = "GroupBox1" Then
        Dim B1emptyTextBoxes = From txt In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                               Where txt.Text.Length = 0
                               Select CStr(txt.Tag)

        Dim B1emptyNumericBox = From num In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)()
                                Where num.Value = 0
                                Select CStr(num.Tag)


        If B1emptyTextBoxes.Any Or B1emptyNumericBox.Any Then
            Dim BothEnumerables = B1emptyTextBoxes.Select(Function(s) s).Concat(B1emptyNumericBox.Select(Function(s) s))
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please Complete the Following Required Fields:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "{0}", String.Join(", ", BothEnumerables)))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If BenchQtyCombo.Text = 1 Then ` was actually referencing a ComboBox, as depending on that value the code will check for additional boxes in GroupBox 2&3 etc, Thank you for the clarification I have also turned on Option Strict :)

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the 2 lists to display them in the `MessageBox`. You need to join the contents of those lists separately instead & then join those strings.

Your `MessageBox` string will need:

```
String.Join(", ", String.Join(", ", B1emptyTextBoxes), String.Join(", ", B1emptyNumericBox))
```